# how to create salesforce's matrix grid?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, salesforce

I am using javascript to creating a matrix grid which have nest row and column summation like [salesforce's matrix grid](http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/large/65953a4bgw1ehgchb7mfyj20t808oac4.jpg), but i have no idea how to make it easier. I think it need some algorithm or data structure knowlege?
Anyone can give me the keyword?

Comment: Did you try to see it as a (n+1)*(n+1) matrix? I guess you should be more precise, provide a sample code etc.

Comment: Are you doing this inside Salesforce?  If so, you might be able to use Visualforce to display your data in a grid without the need for javascript.